# Can I get notified when there's an SE Data Explorer data dump?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

As it is now, I'm checking every day if there is a new data dump. If I were notified, I would not have to keep checking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The blog supports individual RSS feeds for each tag. Data dumps are posted under the `cc-wiki-dump` tag, so you can watch the [RSS feed for that tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/feed/) and you'll see each new post